# Overriding symbols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm using a library called SwiftyJSON, and in it I encountered this:

```
 func ==(lhs: JSONValue, rhs: JSONValue) -> Bool {
  ..stuff here 
  }
```

Now it seems that whenever I use my == symbol on other datatypes (for example I was just comparing uigesturerecognizer directions), it throws an error and complains. It almost seems that in this case, the author ruined "==" for everything. When looking at the code, though, wouldn't this mean "==" only kicks in (will override) whenever I compare something of type JSONValue against something else of type JSONValue?

If so, then what are some thoughts as to why it would throw errors on all other datatype not defined in the file?

The file with this is: https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.swift

It almost seems like i'd have to literally redefine all datatypes within swiftyjson file to be good.

Thanks so much!

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I just [tried this in a playground](https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/3642ab6095496dfe1355) and it compiled and ran fine. You say _"it throws an error and complains"_ What is the error, on what code?

Comment: You've actually run into a Swift beta 5 bug, where the compiler gets confused about which `==` declaration it should use when comparing raw option sets (`RawOptionSetType`), in your case `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection`.

Comment: @Nate so does this mean equality checks (==) are not going to be possible for me unless I handle every type of data that I'll need to  perform == checks on?

Comment: No, I think it's just `RawOptionSetType` implementors like `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection`. If you need equality on those you can compare the results of their `toRaw()` method. That is: `if a.toRaw() == b.toRaw() { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't indicate which error you get, but I assume you mean something like "type couldn't be converted to JSONValue in ==." That doesn't mean that JSONValue is impacting other types. It's just that Swift is complaining that the type you're trying to compare can't be compared with ==. Swift tries to find something to convert it to, and JSONValue is the one that it chose to say it can't convert it to. It might just as well have said that your type can't be converted to Int (and often you'll see it say it can't convert to UInt8). Hopefully the compiler will get better about picking its error message here in future releases.

Comment: Sorry you are correct (exactly so) abotu my error. Thanks so i'm a little confused - what should I do to address this? I need to be able to use == since it's a fundamental part of software development :)

Comment: See @NateCook's comment. The problem is that Swift can't currently handle `==` testing on that specific class. Hopefully that will be addressed in future betas.

Comment: that's right @NateCook .toRaw worked :) thanks to all for helping me and giving me a pair of eyes. I really appreciate this.